# What is a good way to store column attributes for a DataTable?

Tags: c#, .net, datatable

In my application, I have a way to define various attributes for each column in a data table.  From these, I dynamically construct a DataTable for data processing and presentation in UI.  I would love if each DataColumn had a Tag(object) property to store all my custom attributes ... but since it doesn't, what are some alternatives?

What I have now is passing them together, like this:

```
void ProcessData(DataTable table, List<CustomColumnAttribute> columns);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`DataColumn.ExtendedProperties`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.extendedproperties.aspx) to store custom information.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [ExtendedProperties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.extendedproperties.aspx) Property of the Data Column object to add the custom column attributes you desire.

Comment: I found this hashtable is always empty, regardless of whether I programmatically add an entry, or manually add an Extended Property to a database column in SSMS.  There must be something to "enable" the datacolumn properties to start working.